# Auto Check form text input data with PHP & Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am making a small internal PHP quiz with a flat TXT database.  This is working fine.

What I am struggling with is, I want the input to auto search if the answer is correct without the user having to press the Submit button.  It should work like the "username availability checker".  I have tried to use and change some of that code but was unsuccessful.

Is there any other way than AJAX to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$myFile = "answers.txt";
}
$line = file($myFile);
$score = 0;
$logo1 = ucwords($_POST["logo1"]);
if(isset($logo1))
{
if($logo1 == trim($line[0])){
echo "correct";
$score ++; 
} 
else{ 
echo "incorrect"; 
}
}
?>
```

Here is my HTML form:

```
    <div id="logo1" class="logo">
        <input type="text" maxlength="26" value="26 characters" name="logo1" id="logo1"  />
        <span id="loader"></span>
    </div> <!-- Close div for #logo1 -->
```

Comment: Have a look at `jQuery.get()` or `jQuery.ajax()` first. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: If you want the search on the server then you must use AJAX. I recommend JQuery to ease the pain if you are new to AJAX. The only non-AJAX way to handle this would be to load the entire quiz into an array (or some data structure) within your javascript.

Comment: You can do this without AJAX, but it does require javascript, and loading (and hiding) all of the data at page load.  But if you are going to do that, why not just use AJAX instead?  jQuery AJAX is pretty painless.